# Flutter/Dart, Switch: Another exception was thrown: A RenderFlex overflowed by 99640 pixels on the right

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I am currently trying to add a switch to the setting page of my android application. However, when I add the code and try to view it on the emulator it throws the following error:

> Another exception was thrown: A RenderFlex overflowed by 99640 pixels on the right.

**Code:**

```
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration (
    color: Colors.white,
    border: Border(
      bottom: BorderSide(width: 1.0, color: Colors.grey)
    ),
  ),
  constraints: BoxConstraints (
    maxHeight: ((width * ratio) * 0.1),
    minWidth: width,
    maxWidth: width,
  ),
  child: Row(
    children: <Widget>[
      Expanded(
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: (width*ratio) * 0.025),
          child: Text('Highlight Identical Numbers', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87, fontSize: fontTextTwoScale, fontFamily: 'Roboto'))
        )
      ),
      Container(
        child: Switch(value: null, onChanged: null,)
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

I am trying to set it up so that there is text that is aligned to the left of the screen and the switch is aligned to the right. I don't understand how a widget can be 99640 pixels overflowed. I dont see a size options for the Switch.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should easily do the job. Customize the ListTile or wrap it inside a Container for your own customization.

```
ListTile(
  title: Text("Setting Text One Title"),
  trailing: Switch(value: true, onChanged: (bool x) {}),
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that is so much more simpler than I was trying to do it.